# Composer behind Proxy with Authentication

Tags: php, proxy, composer-php, redhat, rhel

I'm using RHEL 6 behind a company proxy. I've set up the env variable (in csh) as follows:

```
setenv http_proxy "http://<user>:<pwd>@<addr>:<port>/"
setenv https_proxy "https://<user>:<pwd>@<addr>:<port>/"
```

When running composer, I get the following errors:

```
Failed to enable crypto
```

The proxy settings worked fine with curl or wget, but fails with composer. Is this a bug with composer? Is there a non ad-hoc way of making this work?

Answer (score 0):

The error seemed to be caused by the version of PHP I was using.

I was using PHP 5.3.3 (the last stable release on RHEL 6). There may be a bug with the file_get_contents implementation in that version. Updating to PHP 5.6 removed the crypto problem.